# Problema con la salida por pantalla con AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Buenas una vez más a tod@s,

Como se ve en el siguiente código, pretendo rellenar un desplegable mediante una comunicación con AJAX. Sin embargo, no consigo que se rellene el desplegable tras pulsar el botón.

Espero que sepáis ver el fallo y podáis ayudarme, porque me he quedado bloqueado en este punto.

Gracias por adelantado.

```js
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", respuesta, false);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function respuesta (){
    var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
    txt = "";
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ARTIST");
        for(i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
            txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("autores").innerHTML = txt;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax-XML</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Comunicación asíncrona con AJAX haciendo uso de XML</h1>
    <hr/>
    <p>Artistas: <select id="autores"></select></p>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Rellena la lista desplegable</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Modificación: un ejemplo del contenido del XML es el siguiente. Lo que no aparece no es más que una sucesión de elementos "CD" con misma estructura interna:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CATALOG>
    <CD>
        <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
        <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
        <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
        <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
        <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
        <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
    </CD>
    .
    .
    .
</CATALOG>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de lo que contiene **cd_catalog.xml**? Recuerda que ese archivo debe estar en el mismo directorio que el html

Comment: Hecho @masterguru!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema de la salida de pantalla es más de **HTML** que de *ajax*, porque estás intentando enviar dentro de un `<select>` unas cadenas de texto separadas por un salto de linea, cuando lo que se espera dentro de un `<select>` son `<option>`.

Por lo tanto, realiza esta modificación en tu código, y donde pone esto:

```javascript
        for(i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
            txt += x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
```

le pones esto:

```javascript
        txt += '<option>Elige un artista</option>'
        for(i = 0; i<x.length; i++){
            artist = x[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue
            txt += '<option value="' + artist + '">' + artist + '</option>';
```

y conseguirás el resultado esperado.

Comment: Pues totalmente de acuerdo una vez más, @masterguru. 

Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate que tu servidor está indicando "text/xml" como directiva de la cabecera content-type de la respuesta http enviada al cliente o fuerza un override a XML del mime type para que parsee el documento como XML:

```js
function loadXMLDoc() {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml");
    xmlhttp.addEventListener("readystatechange", respuesta, false);
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```